# How to initialize once for all a static field of a custom editor in unity

Tags: c#, unityscript

I have a custom editor wich has a static field.

Suppose you have a static field of type `MyObject`:

```
public class myEditor : Editor {

...

private static MyObject myObj;

...
}
```

I'd like to initialize the field `myObj` directly on the same line of the declaration, but in this way I get a `TypeInitializationException`.

I could initialize  the field `myObj` in the method `OnEnable`, but in this way I have to use an if statement like the following:

```
if ( myObj == null )
    myObj = new MyObject();
```

Is there a way to initialize `myObj` once for all without using if statement?

Comment: Is this the code that you are using? I ask because it looks like `field` shouldn't be there and would cause a compilation error.

Comment: Of course no, sorry now I edit :)

Comment: Have you examined the [`TypeInitializationException.InnerException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception.aspx) property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a static constuctor

```
Static myEditor(){
    myObj = new MyObject();
}
```

This will run the first time you access the class